# Implementing Security for Ajax calls

Tags: ajax, security

I am facing difficulty in making my Ajax request secure.
The problem is Data tampering. I have read about this problem and it is suggested that never trust the information what ever is coming from client. It can be very well changed using fiddler or any such tool. We need to validate in server side as well. But my question is how to validate.

Let's see one example.
Suppose I have Employee information in database and I have exposed one method GetEmployeeDetailByEmployeeId. Before any employee make this request he will be authenticated with userId and password and authorized whether user of this type are allowed to make this request or not.

But if one employee gives employeeId of some other employee, he will actually gets the data which he is not supposed to see. To fix  this issue we have two solution
1. We should check the request against the database, whether the information requested by the person is meant for him or he is the manager of that guy
2. We should somehow validate in app layer itself whether we should reject the call or not.

First approach is performance intensive where I have to make database request and finding the association of record, also it will add cost to development.

Pls suggest which way to go and do we have any better solution to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: If reading from the database to update an employee record is too expensive, then maybe you need a better database, or a caching scheme. What you want needs to be done on the backend, as a business-rule check, and there is no magic bullet that will let you make the decision without the data. Please explain why reading from the database is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you need to check it at your back-end side, otherwise your application is likely to exploit by a kid.

**Update**

you need to implement an authorisation mechanism in your back-end, then after you load the permissions at the beginning, you can add it to the user session, so you don't need to look-up the database each time, you just need to check the user permission against the task required permission.

**More**

To implement the authentication mechanism: Goal, `user` can see it's own profile but `supervisor` can see everyone within his `department`.

- `user` A has the `user_id` already loaded at the session, let say `user_id = 123`
- `user` A can only request his information so `if (user_id == req_user_id)` then show the information, otherwise show error.
- `user` B has the permission value of `100`, let's call him `supervisor` then. Now `if (user_id == req_profile_id)` is not **true** we will check the permission. Let say the task permission for this particular task is `10` so `if (user_perm >= task_perm)`, go ahead and check the department, if both the requested user and current user are at the same department, then show the information, otherwise show an error.

this should works based on your information.

Comment: That's true, but for adding checks for every operation, I need to read database which is very costly. Some time the association may not be straight forward and I need to do join on few tables as well. What if we have some option to validate whether the request is genuine and originated from correct source. Similar to Hash or some digital signature kind of stuff..

Comment: @Gaurav in any case, you need to check it out again, a user could be a trusted user, however someone can attacks on behalf of that ...

Comment: Permission is not enough in this case. Say, I will be permission like EmployeeDetailInfoViewPermission. If one malicious employee passed other employeeId he will get the data. As he will be having that permission. I am looking for some solution which will not hurt performance and is easier in implementation as well.

Comment: @Gaurav let say `user_id = 10`, then you have `req_user_id` from clients as well. Simply `if (user_id == req_user_id)` go ahead, else show the access denied error. You just need to load the `user_id` when you're authenticating the user. I hope I understood the problem well ...

Comment: Thanks Floyd for your update... Still I have few concerns. If we have business logic where we need to show the employee information to their corresponding manager. In this scenario above logic will not work right? It is not always true that we server the information of which he is the owner. Sometime we need to show the information which is some how associated with him. Say for example GetDepartmentInfoByDepartmentId. Here we will be showing the department detail in which he is currently working. How we are going to add security for these calls? Do we need to check EmpDept table. Extra Db call